# How to find xpath of js rendered element for puppeteer

Tags: node.js, xpath, puppeteer

Im trying to interact with a js rendered page. Essentially this is a free widget from tradingview; however, the color of the lines is not something I can change. (yes there is an override, however, it only affects 1 line) I need to be able to change 2 lines.

[Trading View Advanced Chart Widget Constructor](https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/)

Can anyone tell me if this is possible with a puppeteer? How can I get XPath for an element which is generated by JS? View source and developer tools do not provide any xpaths to the elements.

[image: Tradingview Volume Settings]

Comment: Same as any other XPath, go into the inspector tool and click on the element, then copy the path. But [there's usually a better selector than the browser-generated ones](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#misusing-developer-tools-generated-selectors). FF gives me `/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]` for this div, which, if I may say so, is garbage, especially for a dynamic JS-driven interactive page that's probably adding and removing elements constantly.

Comment: @ggorlen those elements do not come up in the inspector tools at all.

Comment: They do for me in FF 102.0.1, but keep in mind the tool is inside an iframe.  I'd select this with `document.querySelector('[data-name="legend-source-item"]')` or `document.querySelector(".item-OYqjX7Sg")` at a quick glance (I am not familiar with the tool and there might be a more permanent-looking parent to hook into).

Comment: @ggorlen tried using those selectors frame loads, but cant interacts with those particular elements.